# I'm getting "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" error. Any ideas?

Tags: c#

So, I created a file and a txt file into the AppData, and I want to overwrite the txt. But when I try to do it, it keeps giving me that error. Any ideas?

```
            string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
            string setuppath = (path + "\\");
            string nsetuppath = (setuppath + "newx" + "\\");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(nsetuppath);

            string hedef2 = (nsetuppath + "commands.txt");
            File.Create(hedef2);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(hedef2);   ----> This is where the error appears.
            sw.WriteLine("Testtest");
```

Comment: `File.Create` returns an *open stream* to the file. That's the "another process" - it's actually you. You can pass an open stream to the constructor of `StreamWriter`.

Comment: File.Create returns a file stream. Streams need to be disposed when they're done being used, they implement the [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable) pattern. If you don't want to use streams, then it's likely the other methods on System.IO.File would suit your needs.

Comment: Please check your task bar to see if any of the application instance is already running and holding the handle to file. The file could be left opened with previous instance. If its your entire code, it does not have closing file statement. So, add a statement to close the file first and then make sure to close all the instances. Then give it a shot. Please post your observations after that.

Comment: File.Create returns a `FileStream` - you should create the `StreamWriter` to take that stream as an input to it's constructor, or simply use `File.WriteAllText` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `using` statement when using streams. The using statement automatically calls Dispose on the object when the code that is using it has completed.

```
        //path to the file you want to create
        string path = @"C:\code\Test.txt";
        // Create the file, or overwrite if the file exists.
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
        {
            byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is some text in the file.");
            // Add some information to the file.
            fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
        }
```

There are many ways of manipulate streams, keep it simple depending on your needs